# Review not helpful while my review is the same as the final result?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I just found my review queues were blocked because:

> Your review on
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22123823 wasn't
>   helpful

I followed the link and found that my opinion was shared by the other reviewer, which aligned with the final result.

[image]

So why was it not helpful?

Comment: You can disagree with the result, but this is most certainly **not a bug**.

Comment: "Thanks" should be removed and never be expanded to "Thank you in advance!". Also, the overall edit pretty much looks like "no improvement whatsoever" to me. Please don't approve such edits.

Comment: A review doesn't suddenly become helpful just because the other review also made the same poor choice in accepting this bad edit.

Comment: Beyond saying "another user agreed with me", how would you defend that edit being useful? That other user is probably serving a suspension as well.

Comment: OK I understand your point, I should have reviewed differently, but I believe this notice should be improved: instead of showing "approved" in bold green font, which is seemingly contradictory to the not helpful notice, it should first tell me that the review was rejected by someone else and for the reasons you gave me above.

Comment: The edit was approved, that already happened. I guess the moderator could have overriden the approval, but it was frankly not worth it. The edit was not useful, but reverting is not useful either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sort of right. This couldn't be an automated ban, because as far as the system is concerned, there was nothing wrong with your review action.

Unfortunately, the system is kinda dumb, in that it has no way of knowing what is or is not a good edit. It assumes that the edit is good if it gets approved, and two people (you included) voted to approve this one.

It turns out that this is actually ***not*** a good edit, and therefore should not have been approved. In other words, you *did* make the wrong decision when reviewing, irrespective of the fact that someone else also made the wrong decision.

Handling these cases is why we have moderators. In this case, you were manually banned from reviewing by a moderator (it wasn't me, not that it matters who it was). They said:

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22123823 wasn't helpful; please review the history of the post and consider how choosing a different action could've helped achieve that outcome more quickly.

I recommend taking that advice and reflecting on why the edit should not have been approved. As honk said:

> "Thanks" should be removed and never be expanded to "Thank you in advance!". Also, the overall edit pretty much looks like "no improvement whatsoever" to me. Please don't approve such edits.

That "Thanks" should be removed is part of the [official guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), because it's considered to be noise. Think of Stack Overflow as being more like Wikipedia than a discussion forum.

By way of comparison, [Josh Caswell's recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54536601/3) is a good example of what an edit to that question *should* have looked like.

[I also made some further edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54536601/4), fixing the grammar, improving the formatting (make the numbered list actually a numbered list), and fleshing out the bare link a bit.

Notice what these latter two sets of edits have in common: they fix *major* issues in the post, and they aren't trivial. They don't leave glaring problems (like "Thanks") unhandled, and they leave the post significantly better than they found it. These are the edits we want to encourage users to make, and since the suggested edits feature is "training wheels" for full editing privileges, these are the types of edits that we want to encourage by approving them.

FYI (if fairness is your concern): the moderator who imposed your temporary ban also imposed a temporary ban on the other person who approved that edit.

Comment: The first few paragraphs sort of imply that a reviewer taking an action that other reviewers disagree on would somehow count against them and result in an automated ban, which isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer which will certainly help me to be a better reviewer. As for the last paragraph, I might not have been very clear expressing myself: I was not looking for a sense of fairness, I came to meta and asked simply because I didn't understand those notices contradicting each other. That's why I flagged the question as `bug` in the first place. Moreover, it's only a one-day ban, why would I spent my time trying to waive such a small ban? Again because I care about what's wrong with my review or the system. If I were you, I would start that paragraph with simply an FYI.

Comment: I realize that, @Siyu. That was the tone I tried to convey with the smiley. But like Rene points out, that could be confusing. Maybe FYI would be better. Man, writing is hard. And I’m out of practice on Meta. Anyone who is compelled, feel free to edit.